# JavaScript- Unable to find and access the selected value in dropdown menu in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use the selected value in the dropdown menu but I don't know how to get it.

Attached code:

```
Cost Value: <input type="text" name="cost">  
   <ul id="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Category</a>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">House</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>

       </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('li').hover(function(){
                $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(400);
            });
            $("#menu").one("click", function(evt){
                document.write(this.selectedText);
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in your click handler, you want to assure that `this` within the handler is the anchor, not the `#menu` `ul`. Also, you probably want `on`, not `one`.

So:

```
$("#menu").on("click", "a", function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault(); // So we don't follow the link
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Notes on that:

1. I used `on`, not `one`, so that the handler isn't removed after the first click.
2. I prevented the default so that the link doesn't get followed and jump your page back to the top.
3. I used `console.log` rather than `document.write` because `document.write` at that point will implicitly do `document.open` and wipe out your page.
4. I used `$(this).text()` to get the text of the anchor.

Comment: but now... how can I use it? I want to assign it

Comment: `var theVariableYouWantToAssignTo = $(this).text();`